# Could not deduce from the context

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, typeclass

I have this type class. But it cannot deduce that type returned from `goal` equals `isGoal`'s first variable's type. How to fix this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}
class Problem p where 
    type State p :: * 
    data Action p :: * 

    goal :: Eq (State p) => State p 
    goal = undefined 

    isGoal :: Eq (State p) => State p -> Bool 
    isGoal s = s == goal
```

**Ended up doing this**

```
class Problem p where 
    type State p :: * 
    data Action p :: * 

    goal :: p -> State p 
    goal = undefined 

    isGoal :: Eq (State p) => p -> State p -> Bool 
    isGoal p s = s == goal p
```

Comment: It would be nice if you'd present error messages in some other way. Screenshots from a Windows console, seriously...

Comment: It doesn't realize you're trying to use `goal` from the same instance.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Copying and pasting from the Windows console is pretty annoying, I can understand preferring to take a screenshot.

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen well, it can't be more annoying than copying and pasting from _a Windows-console screenshot_! Question is, why use the Windows console in the first place? Apart from switching to a better OS entirely, there's also the option of WinGHCi.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Well you have a point, I'd forgotten how annoying screenshots also are. I thought you could just paste them into SO posts but apparently not. And I use WinGHCi myself, but it has its bugs, and my impression is the GHC docs recommend the console.

Comment: What could be more annoying? Typing out that to text editor and having no computer of your own.

Comment: The biggest problem with screenshots is that there's no guarantee that the image will always be hosted and available. Please copy and paste!

Comment: Screen shot is just additional information. It's already described in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hint is right there in the error message:

> N.B.: ‘State’ is a type function, and may not be injective

What this means: an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) *f* is a function where from *f*(*x*) = *f*(*y*) it follows that *x* = *y*. Now, we're talking type-level here, so if `State` were injective, it would follow from `State p ~ State q` that `p ~ q`.

In `s == goal`, the compiler knows it needs to unify `goal` with `s` (because `==` always compares values of the same type), so there we have it:

```
s :: State p
goal :: State q
State p ~ State q
```

but because `State` is *not* injective, the compiler can't infer that `p ~ q`, i.e. that we're only talking about a single instance of the type class.

Why not? Well, you could come up with:

```
instance Problem Int where
  type State Int = Bool
  goal = True

instance Problem Double where
  type State Double = Bool
  goal = False
```

Now we have `State Int ~ State Double`. Yet obviously `Int` and `Double` aren't the same type, and they define `goal` in contradictory ways.

---

“How to fix this” – well, you need to redesign the class.

- You can use

  ```
  class Problem p where 
    data State p :: *
  ```

  In this case, `State` *is* injective, because every instantiation needs to be hard-baked into a single `instance Problem`.
- If you need the ability to define the actual `State` types elsewhere, you need to give the compiler an explicit hint which `p` should be used for `goal`. The usual solution are proxies or – preferrable IMO – [tagged](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.1/docs/Data-Tagged.html) values:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
  import Data.Tagged

  class Problem p where 
    type State p :: * 

    goal :: Eq (State p) => Tagged p (State p)
    goal = Tagged undefined

    isGoal :: Eq (State p) => Tagged p (State p) -> Bool 
    isGoal = isGoalDef

  isGoalDef :: forall p . Eq (State p) => Tagged p (State p) -> Bool 
  isGoalDef (Tagged s) = s == g
      where (Tagged g) = goal :: Tagged p (State p)
  ```